# Understanding of how does the CPU works

Tags: memory, cpu

I'm doing a school project on how does the computer processor work in detail and I would like to check if i understood that principle.

[image: Scheme]

According to this scheme I'd like to clarify a few things:

1. Does the number of 'wires' in the chip bus represents number of bits
   the processor works with, in this case 8, meaning it's 8-bit
   processor and if there would be 32 of those it would be 32-bit
   processor?

Of course correspondingly with the number of space for 0's and 1's in the Register Units.

2. If so, how is a letter represented by 8 bits of information, e.g. A
   = 01000001, transferred by the bus on 32 'wires'?

I would like to continue on with my list but I've just realized that all other points depend on answers on these questions above.

**Edit: Except maybe for this one, each processor has it's processor clock, is it right? Each tick means undergoing one action, right? (Meaning, for example, transferring one Byte (8 bits in this case) of information from RAM to Control Unit.) Does it mean that a hypothetical processor which clock ticking once per second has 1Hz?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Does the number of 'wires' in the chip bus represents number of bits the processor works with, in this case 8, meaning it's 8-bit processor

Yes it does!

- and if there would be 32 of those it would be 32-bit processor?

Yes, correct, it would be 32-bit processor

- If so, how is a letter represented by 8 bits of information, e.g. A = 01000001, transfered by the bus on 32 'wires'?

This not pronblem at all, is it? You can fill the rest of "wires" with 0 like

01000001 0000000000000 .....

Comment: Thanks, it all looks simple but I never thought it would be simple as well in reality. Do you know the answer to the question I have edited in, in the original post?

Comment: The answer is yes as well, take a look at http://smallbusiness.chron.com/ghz-mean-computer-processor-66857.html